# LAMP Server HTTP-> HTTPS redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, https

I have 2 LAMP servers with the same version of Apache, both running Wordpress.
SSL is working on both servers (although the test server uses a cert for a different domain).

On both I have the following .htaccess file (/var/www/html/.htaccess):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

The test server redirects to HTTPS correctly, but the production server does not attempt to redirect at all.  I can manually browse the production site via HTTPS.

The permissions on the .htaccess file is 755 and owned by apache:apache on both server.

In order to make sure that the redirect on the test site was because of the .htaccess file, I changed it by removing the following:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
> ```

The redirect on on the test site stopped until I added it back.

Is there something that may have been done on the test site that needs to be done on production?

Comment: Did you checked that mod_rewrite in enabled on production server?

Comment: Yes, both servers have `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue so I guess I jumped the gun on posting this question, but I'll leave it here - maybe it will save somebody some time.

In the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file, I had `AllowOverride` set to `None` still on the production site for the document root directory.
Here is what it looks like now (with the redirect working):

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```